# mounting HDD as user or otherwise; permissions

Tags: mount, users, external-hdd

I am not new to Ubuntu but use it primarily as a media centre. I am familiar with the terminal, but only for basics eg software updates and cutting and pasting.

I don't quite understand the file system and permissions. Although I understand to use sudo before commands to perform as superuser.
I have discovered that one of my ext hard drives has been locked. When I look in nautilus under /media I see it has been moved from my userfolder `/media/mark` and put in a new guest folder `/media/guest-Wwm1UC`.  Permissions are locked and I can't see what they are.

What the hell I have done I have no idea. I suspect I was drunk one night and moved some files or done some thing whilst logged in as a guest and not as user. This is a reasonable guess! I have opened nautilus as su and tried to change permissions of the folder and drive. When I do this nautilus crashes each time. My solution to access the drive and folders was to open nautilus as su and unmount the drive.

When I reopen Nautilus as user I have my normal permissions restored. 
My question is, how could I have created this? Mounting the drive as guest? 
After this experience, I feel I should do some reading and teach myself the file systems, permissions and users etc. ( Not `/etc` =) )

Comment: I cannot recommend a textbook since I do not know any. I believe most users in this community learned by doing, which I recommend you start as well in case you cannot find the perfect book. Here For example you tried to battle the problem with force (running nautilus as sudo) without understanding what the problem actually is. The `ls` command should help you, since it can show you the file/folder permissions. Try this for example: `cd /media` and `ls -l`. It will show you the ownership and permissions. If you need help, edit your question and add the output of the `ls` command.

Comment: Ah yes, learn by doing. I have solved a number of problems myself by visiting forums like this one and if the solution isn't found I will appropriate a solution for a similar issue and use intuition. This rarely means that get an understanding of the problem however. Additionally, I mainly use my Linux PC passively, and there is a lot of time between bouts of advanced use or even simple use of the terminal. I find these ad hoc solutions helpful for resolution at the time, but its information that I usually lose fairly quickly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you logged in as a guest user, mounted the external drive and didn't unmount it. Now the (ephemeral) guest user has exclusive access rights to the file system on the drive and to unmount it (as long as it stays mounted).

The easiest solution would be to unmount the drive as super-user.

### Method 1: Gnome Disks

You can unmount file systems through *Gnome Disks*.

1. Select the drive and the partition.
2. Press the *unmount button* crested with a black square (■). Depending on access rights Gnome Disks may ask for a super-user password.
3. Mount it again through Gnome Disks or Nautilus or however you do it usually.

This method works usually for all unmounting procedures. Though in your particular case I don't know how UDisks (the subsytem allowing regular users to mount file systems) behaves if a different user mounted the file system originally. Try the other method if it doesn't work.

### Method 2: Command-line

1. Unmount the drive as super-user:

   ```
   sudo umount <MOUNTPOINT>
   ```

   or

   ```
   sudo umount <DEVICE>
   ```
2. Mount it with your regular user like you normally do (e. g. through the side bar in Nautilus).

---

It's also possible to change the mount options and move the mount point to give another user access without unmounting the file system in the process but that requires a little investigation and is more complicated. If you want that please open a new question and stress that you don't want to unmount and leave me a comment to draw my attention to it.

Comment: Thanks David. I have validated your answer. I unmounted via Nautilus as superuser, closed that window and remounted in Nautilus as user. In-fact, it was already mounted as user when I reopened nautilus.